# How to use LocalBroadcastManager without Activity

Tags: java, android, localbroadcastmanager

I had my class '*ABC*' by extending the `BroadcastReceiver`. But recently, I stumbled upon `LocalBroadcastManager`.

here is my class declaration:

```
public class ABC extends BroadcastReceiver {}
```

So ABC is working as the listener and based on the action it would call another object.

I checked everywhere whether I can use `LocalBroadcastManager` here without an activity. Actually class ABC is a core application class where it doesn't connect to any UI component.

Let me know how can I use `LocalBroadcastManager` in my scenario.

I'm new to Android. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a bit late for the answer but I hope it'd be useful to you.

The first step is having a class which extends the application. This will be used to get the application context from outside an Activity.

```
public class AppContext extends Application {

    private static AppContext instance;

    public AppContext() {
      instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
      return instance;
    }
}
```

Then add the following piece of code where you want to send the message to LocalBroadcasr

```
Intent intent = new Intent("intent-filter");
intent.putExtra("message", "your-message-here");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(AppContext.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Finally, your class ABC will receive this intent as I show you next

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

public class ABC{

public ABC(){
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //receive your message here
      String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    };
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(AppContext.getContext()).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("intent-filter")); 
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
LocalBroadcastManager  localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(receiver); // or other operations
```