# Activity, Context methods and objects in non-activity classes

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm making an android app that uses device sensors and location. The data from both sources will be used to calcute some things about orientation. So far i created two non-activity classes, one for sensor management and one for location management. The problem is when i want to use something that needs Activity or Context to be done, for example: show the dialog by calling `startResolutionForResult()`, and check the result in `onActivityResult()`. `startResolutionForResult()`needs Activity to show a dialog.
What's the best approach to solve this? I've decided to use context as a field member of each non-activity class, but i'm not sure if it's the best option.

**Update**
Here is a part of my code i'm reffering to.

In `onCreate()` method i call `checkLocationSettings()` method to check if location is on. `Then onResult()` callback fires where i can determine what to do depending on location settings. When location is off, it shows dialog called by

```
status.startResolutionForResult((Activity)getBaseContext(), REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS)
```

The result of users decision is available in `onActivityResult()` which is a part of MainActivity.class
Everything works like a charm, but i'm concernd about **(Activity)getBaseContext()** in particular.

**GoogleServiceLocationProvider.class**

```
public class GoogleServiceLocationProvider extends ContextWrapper implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> {

private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 3;

private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;   // 10 seconds
private static final int DISPLACEMENT = 10;             // 10 meters

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;

private Location lastLocation;
private long lastTime;

LocationFinder.LocationUpdateListener locationUpdateListener;
private boolean isListenerRunning;

private LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest;

public GoogleServiceLocationProvider(Context base) {
    super(base);

    buildApiGoogleClient();
    createLocationRequest();
    buildLocationSettingsRequest();
}

private void buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    locationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
}

public void checkLocationSettings() {
    if(googleApiClient != null && locationSettingsRequest != null){
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                        googleApiClient,
                        locationSettingsRequest
                );
        result.setResultCallback(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
    final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
            break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
            try {
                status.startResolutionForResult((Activity)getBaseContext(), REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            }
            break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
            break;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    useGoogleLocationServiceAPI();
}

private void useGoogleLocationServiceAPI(){
    googleServiceLocationProvider = new GoogleServiceLocationProvider(this);
    googleServiceLocationProvider.checkLocationSettings();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode){

        case PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST:
            switch(resultCode){
                case RESULT_OK:
                    isGoogleLocationService = true;
                    useGoogleLocationServiceAPI();
                    break;
                case RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.google_location_service_missing),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    useAndroidLocationAPI();
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch(resultCode){
                case RESULT_OK:
                    break;
                case RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.location_off_message),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: pass `Context` as parameter to function

Comment: Use getApplicationContext it's scope is application wide.

Comment: @AndroidBeginner this is not available everywhere.

Comment: I posted you some code you might want to take a look at.

Comment: @AndroidBeginner you cannot open dialogs with `applicationContext`, it has no window and therefore cause an `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: You can use a **LocalBroadcastReceiver**, to which you can send broadcasts using a **LocalBroadcastManager** that you can obtain from the global application context as http://stackoverflow.com/a/21723614/2413303

Comment: I updated my answer. You might want to check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

By this line of code `status.startResolutionForResult((Activity)getBaseContext(), /*...*/);` you are assuming that the `context` that has been passed to your constructor `GoogleServiceLocationProvider` is an `Activity` which might not be always the case. What if you were using a `Service`? This line `(Activity)getBaseContext()` would throw a `ClassCastException`.

If you need an `Activity` in order to make sure your `GoogleServiceLocationProvider` has it all, why don't just require an `Activity` instance instead of a `Context` in your constructor?

```
private Activity activity;
public GoogleServiceLocationProvider(Activity activity) {
    super(activity.getContext());
    this. activity = activity;
    //...
}
```

You would use that later in your `onResult` method like so:

```
@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
    //...
    status.startResolutionForResult(this.activity,  REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
    //...
}
```

Now to answer your first question.

**Android fact**

You're always running your code where the `context` is available somehow.

Whether it's an `Activity`, a `Service`, an `Application`, a `BoradcastReceiver` ... You'll have a direct/indirect access to your `context`.

**Therefore**

The simplest yet more efficient and decoupled approach is to pass this `context` as a reference to your custom classes. You can keep a reference to that `context` somewhere in your `class` (dependency injection) in order to use it later but be aware of [leaks](http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/05/23/memory-leaks.html).

**Some code**

```
class MyClass {
    //...
    public void doSomethingWithTheContext (Context context) {
        //...
        context.doThis(/*...*/);
        //...
    }
}
```

**Usage**

From an `Activity`, an `Application`, a `Service` ... (all extends `Context`)

```
myInstanceOfMyClass.doSomethingWithTheContext(this);
```

From a `Fragment`

```
myInstanceOfMyClass.doSomethingWithTheContext(getActivity());
```

**Related question**

[Using Application context everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere)

Answer (score 2):

Passing context's to each and every class is one option. But I'd prefer keeping these classes loosely coupled and use an `EventBus` to send and retrieve data. As  It provides a centralized way to notify software components that are interested in a specific type of event. There exists no direct coupling between the code of the publisher of the event and the code that receives it. A well designed decoupled system will reduce the need to make changes across components in case anything changes.

The library is available here: [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Here's an even simpler tutorial that explains the same:[How to use the greenrobot EventBus library](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/11/28/android-how-to-use-the-greenrobot-eventbus/)

Comment: I do agree that `EventBus` is a greet way to manage data transfer. But don't you think this is an overkill for such a question? And the thing is that his classes require a `context` in order to do what they're meant, so you're not decoupling anything by using `EventBus`.

Comment: No, EventBus is a reasonable solution when you're trying to communicate with Activities, because of their transient nature.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass either the `Context` or the `Activity` objects to a method, like this:

```
public void startResolutionForResult(Context context) {
    contex.showYourAlert();
}
```

To get the `onActivityResult()` values, you could pass them as parameters too, or just create the `startResolutionForResult` method inside your `Activity`.