# How do I send data from a class in one package to a class in another package?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, android-intent, package

I have developed an Android app which opens up a Unity app which will then return to the Android app. I have created a plugin Java class MyPlugin which acts as a bridge between Android and Unity. Unity calls this method and passes in a float as a parameter. The plugin MyPlugin is in the package com.example.unity and is in the path unityLibrary/java.

How do I access this float from classes in my main package in app/java? Or send this data from MyPlugin to the other classes?

My project structure looks like this:

```
-app
 -java
  -com.company.package1
   -Android class files
-unityLibrary
 -java
  -com
   -example.unity
    -MyPlugin.java
```

I have tried using an intent but aren't sure exactly what to do. All the examples I have seen deal with everything being in the same package. This is what I tried. printText() is a method in MyPlugin which is called from Unity:

```
public void printText(float num)
    {
        surfaceArea = num;
        System.out.println("Text from Unity: "+num);

        Intent intent =  new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ""+num);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        mainActivity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Update 16/07/2021:
Following Rolland Costomarob's advice, I am now using a Broadcast sender and receiver. My plugin now looks like this:

```
package com.example.unity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyPlugin {
    private static final MyPlugin ourInstance = new MyPlugin();

    private static final String LOGTAG = "AltGras";

    public static MyPlugin getInstance() { return ourInstance; }
    public static BroadcastSender mainActivity;
    public float surfaceArea ;

    private MyPlugin() {
        mainActivity = new BroadcastSender();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Created MyPlugin");
    }

    public void printText(float num)
    {
        surfaceArea = num;
        System.out.println("printText: Text from Unity: "+num);
        mainActivity.SendBroadcast(num);
    }
}
```

BroadcastSender.java:

```
package com.example.unity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class BroadcastSender extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void SendBroadcast(float surfaceArea){
        System.out.println("In MainActivityUnity.SendBroadcast");

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        if (intent == null)
        {
            System.out.println("SendBroadcast: intent is null");
        }
        if (this == null)
        {
            System.out.println("SendBroadcast: this is null");
        }
        intent.setAction("com.alternativegrass.alternativegrassapp.CUSTOM_SENDDATA_INTENT");
        System.out.println("SendBroadcast: intent = "+intent);
        intent.putExtra("com.alternativegrass.alternativegrassapp.EXTRA_SURFACEAREA", ""+surfaceArea);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
```

The line it is complaining about is:
sendBroadcast(intent);

Answer (score 1):

please try with broadcast and receiver.
intent can't use for the different app.
so you need to send broadcast from one app, receive data with filter.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm

for example

in your manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and define receiver

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Action: " + intent.getAction() + "\n");
            sb.append("URI: " + intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME).toString() + "\n");
            String log = sb.toString();
            Log.d(TAG, log);
            Toast.makeText(context, log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

and register receiver

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
    this.registerReceiver(br, filter);
```

send broadcast like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.broadcast.MY_NOTIFICATION");
intent.putExtra("data", "Nothing to see here, move along.");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

you will receive message.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have got the toast working. I get a NullPointerException from MyPlugin when putExtra in printText() is called. I do intent.setAction("com.company.appname.CUSTOM_SENDDATA_INTENT") followed by intent.putExtra("com.company.appname.EXTRA_SURFACEAREA", surfaceArea);

Comment: Broadcast can also use between different apps. if one app broadcast some data, and other app can receive the data with filter.

Comment: If all I want to do is send and receive a float without any of the toast or connectivity stuff, what do I need to do? In printText(), do I just do Intent intent = new Intent; then intent.putExtra("com.company.appname.EXTRA_SURFACEAREA", surfaceArea);?

Where do I register the receiver? What do I pass into the IntentFilter constructor?

Comment: once  you register broadcast receiver, you can get any broadcast intent with filter, so if you know the intent action of sending part, your registered receiver can get the broadcast data.

Comment: Where should I register it? I registered it in MainActivity.onCreate but I get the following error:

AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

The line throwing the error is:
intent.putExtra("com.company.appname.EXTRA_SURFACEAREA", surfaceArea) which is in the printText() method of MyPlugin.java.

Comment: OK, then I will make new another answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is sending part (first apk)

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            SendBroadcast();
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    public void SendBroadcast(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.example.broadcast.MY_NOTIFICATION");
        intent.putExtra("Value",109.3f);
        intent.putExtra("Message","Working well");
        Log.e("Broadcast","Send broadcast");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0,10000);
    }
```

this broadcast data every 10 sec

and this is receive part (second apk)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BroadcastReceiver br = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.example.broadcast.MY_NOTIFICATION");
        this.registerReceiver(br, filter);
    }

    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Action: " + intent.getAction() + "\n");
            sb.append("Message: " + intent.getStringExtra("Message") + "\n");
            sb.append("Value: "+ intent.getFloatExtra("Value",0.0f));
            String log = sb.toString();
            Log.e("Broadcast ","Received");
            Log.d(TAG, log);
            Toast.makeText(context, log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

and this is result log

2021-07-16 01:18:40.488 2337-2337/com.example.broadcastreceiver E/Broadcast: Received 2021-07-16 01:18:40.488 2337-2337/com.example.broadcastreceiver D/MyBroadcastReceiver: Action: com.example.broadcast.MY_NOTIFICATION
Message: Working wellValue: 109.3

Comment: I haven't tried that yet but I have realised why I get a NullPointerException. It's because I'm doing mainActivity.sendBroadcast(intent). I have mainActivity declared as public static Activity mainActivity but I didn't initialise it. I have now created a new instance of it in the MyPlugin constructor with mainActivity = new Activity(); but I still get the error. What should I do to make it not null?

Comment: Okay, I've moved all my intent code from the MyPlugin class to BroadcastSender which extends Activity and created a new instance of BroadcastSender called mainActivity in the MyPlugin constructor. Then in MyPlugin.printText(), I call mainActivity.SendBroadcast(). I still get the NullPointerException when I call sendBroadcast(intent) in the BroadcastSender.SendBroadcast() method.

Comment: I have updated my original question with the new code.

Comment: are you going to send like this? MyPlugin plugin = new MyPlugin(); plugin.printText(value); ?

Comment: No. The plugin instance is created in Unity which has a different way to how Android creates it. That bit it working fine and sends the correct value to printText. It's just the sendBroadcast that isn't working.

Comment: please try with this way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758613/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager-without-activity

Comment: you fixed issue?

Comment: Sorry, it was the weekend so I didn't look until now. I have added the code from your link with a few adjustments to fix some errors. I'm currently getting an error 'package androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content does not exist'. Probably something to do with gradle. I have added the AppContext code in my BroadcastSender class in com.example.unity. Is this where I should add it or should I put it in the same package as my Android app files?

Comment: Also, it says LocalBroadcastManager is deprecated. Will it even work because my Unity app is kind of seperate from my Android app.

Comment: sorry, it was a bit busy in these days.have you fix your problem?

Comment: No not yet. It's getting a bit overwhelming so I haven't looked at it today.

Comment: you can try context.sendbroadcast(); from  your plugin.

Comment: So do AppContext.getContext().sendBroadcast(); instead of using a LocalBroadcastManager?

Comment: yes,  you need to context to sendbroadcast.
getApplicationContext().sendbroadcast();
or you can get context form constructor.

Comment: I do AppContext appContext = new AppContext(); and then appContext.getContext().sendBroadcast(intent); but get a NullPointerException

Comment: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:448)
        at com.example.unity.BroadcastSender.SendBroadcast(BroadcastSender.java:46)

Comment: this means the context is null i guess.

Comment: I have done 'if (appContext == null)' and 'if (appContext.getContext() == null)' and they both tell me they are not null.

Comment: if context is not null , then intent is null?

Comment: intent isn't null either. I've printed it and it comes out as 'SendBroadcast: intent = Intent { act=com.alternativegrass.alternativegrassapp.CUSTOM_SENDDATA_INTENT }'

Comment: can you share your full code? if you can, please send to my email. then I will find error for you.

Comment: It's for my job so I can't share the whole project but I can send you the plugin source code which sends the broadcast. What is your e-mail address?

Comment: Or I could make a mini version of the project with all the unnecessary bits taken out and send it to you.

Comment: the simpler the better

Comment: What is your e-mail address?

Comment: I have added my project to GitHub here: https://github.com/ParagramApps/BroadcastSenderProject. It contains the Android project AndroidUnityBroadcastSender and the Unity project embedunityandroid (I'm not sure if this uploaded correctly. Please let me know).

Comment: I have also added the plugin project here: https://github.com/ParagramApps/UnityAndroidPlugin. What I do is make changes to the code in the AndroidUnityBroadcastSender project, copy to the changes to the duplicated files here then run the plugin project which creates a .aar file in Assets/Plugins/Android. I then copy the .aar to the Unity project's Assets/Plugins/Android folder then Export the Unity project to androidBuild folder then run the Android project. Pretty convoluted, I know, and I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it. Let me know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, if you just run the Android project as it is, it will bring up a screen with one button. Click it and it will run the Unity app. Press the 'Send data to Android' button on the Unity app which should generate the error that we have been discussing. If you click the 'Next' button, it will quit the Unity app and return to the Android app. I don't know how familiar you are with Unity but you will need to install it, preferably version 2019.4.21 which is the one that I use. Higher versions may not work properly.

Comment: embedunityandroid is empty
can't build your app.

Comment: I have re-uploaded it now. Please try again.